# ScadaLTS Features supporting MMS and GOOSE Driver

Tags: mms, goose, scadalts

I am doing a project to monitor my virtual IED's with a SCADA system. However, the driver that i want to use to transmit information is MMS or GOOSE. So does ScadaLTS support IEC 60870-5-104 (MMS) and IEC 61850 (GOOSE)? If not, do you have any recommendation to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean IEC 61850 over MMS not IEC 60870-5-104. The later has nothing to do with MMS. An IEC 61850 MMS data source for ScadaLTS could be developed using [OpenIEC61850](https://www.beanit.com/iec61850) a Java open source stack.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of OpenIEC61850.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we do not have but it seems to me that it can be done the appropriate OPC server.